# OOP programming method question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, domain-driven-design

I have 2 objects, Area and SurfBreak. Area has many SurfBreaks and a SurfBreak publishes its conditions based on wind,wave,tide info  from Area.  This bit I've done an it works well:-)

I now have list of forecast data for Area - future changes to Area's attributes.

Whats the best OOP method to show  the Surfbreaks conditions using forecast data for Area ?

Many thanks
Andy

----Updated---

Its a rails app

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :area
    has_many :forecasts, :through => :area

def has_swell
        wind = "#{area.swelldir}"
        beachstart = "#{breakstr}"
        beachend = "#{breakend}"
        if (   ((wind.to_i) + 360 - (beachstart.to_i)) % 360  <= ((beachend.to_i) + 360 - (beachstart.to_i)) % 360   )
                   "#{area.swelldir} Has Incoming swell "
            else
                   "#{area.swelldir} No Swell"

        end
    end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :spots
    has_many :forecasts

class Forecast < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :area
```

The DB tables are the objects in rails. I've got Area and Spot working nicely but I now want to display  forecasts for a  spot. This is the bit I'm not sure about.

```
mysql> desc areas;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descrip  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| winddir  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| windspd  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| swelldir | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| swellhgt | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tide     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat      | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lng      | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc spots;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descrip  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| breakstr | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| breakend | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| offstr   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| offend   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| besttide | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| area_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc forecasts;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| forecastdate | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| area_id      | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| winddir      | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| windspd      | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| swelldir     | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| swellhgt     | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tide         | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So say an Area has 24 Forecast rows in a DB , one for every hour in the future. In my app 
what is the best way to output a spots forecast conditions. Without changing the relevant values in the Area as Areas hold the current conditions. I could just pull all the forecast data into an array an loop through it changing the Area object data, but this doesn't seem very OOP to me ?

As output I'm after something like

```
Current Spot Details   (Using spot methods on Area attributes) 
xxx   


Forecast Details for this spot (Using spot methods on Forecast attributes )
Hour 1 xxx
Hour 2 xxx
Hour 3 xxx
..
```

Sorry if this is not very well explained.

Regards
Andy

Comment: We'll need to see code in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class Area sounds like it is doing too many things, and it is changing for different reasons. Separate it out so the Area has a list of WeatherData or something, so your forecasting code can iterate through the WeatherData without Area having to change. Your WeatherData object can include a flag saying whether it's real data or a forecast.

Comment: You helped me change my design , the Area no longer hold the conditions its now in the forecast with the most recent forecast data being the current conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Class Area{
Wind wind;
Wave wave;
Tide tide;
}  

Class SurfBreak extends Area{
//some SurfBreaks' field

public ForecastDetail getForecastDetail(){
//operate directly onwind wave tide fields and calculate
}

}
```

Comment: @org.life.java much better than my answer ;)

Comment: The program is in rails with the following models

Comment: class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :area
 has_many :forecasts, :through => :area

def has_swell
  wind = "#{area.swelldir}"
  beachstart = "#{breakstr}"
  beachend = "#{breakend}"
  if (   ((wind.to_i) + 360 - (beachstart.to_i)) % 360  <=  ((beachend.to
_i) + 360 - (beachstart.to_i)) % 360   )
                   "#{area.swelldir} Has Incoming swell "
         else
                   "#{area.swelldir} No Swell"
  #return true
  end
 end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :spots
 has_many :forecasts

class Forecast < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :area

Comment: @AndyM can you please update it in your question its not readable

Comment: Sorry , I've now updated the question in the correct place :-)

Comment: I want to show a spot and current condtion. ie spot.has_swell.

Comment: and also put the values from forecasts for the area into spot so I can list the all future conditions by linking forecast-->area--->spot. Sorry its hard for me to explain. I'll update the question some more

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained exactly how you developed first part of the problem (relations between Area and SurfBreaks), but, I would consider using of Observer design pattern here. So SurfBreaks would be Observers of Area changes.